# Why isn't officedown for Rmarkdown outputting formatted text?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, officer, officedown

I am new to using Rmarkdown and officer/officedown, so maybe there is an easy fix for this, but I'm at a loss.  I'm trying to create a Word document for reports using officedown/officer so that I can have greater control over the look of text and such.  I kept getting odd results with my own code so tried to basically just copy/paste a very simple example from https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/formatting-properties.html (the example from section 7.1). Below is the code that I input into Rmarkdown (with appropriate --- and ``` {r} added where needed). And the further down is the result I received minus the typical warnings that I'm not concerned about."

```
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "7/21/2021"
output: officedown::rdocx_document
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library("officedown")
library("officer")
library("dplyr")
```

```
properties1 <- fp_text(color = "#006699", bold = TRUE, font.size = 50)
properties2 <- fp_text(color = "#C32900", bold = TRUE, font.size = 50)
ftext1 <- ftext("hello ", properties1)
ftext2 <- ftext("World", properties2)
paragraph <- fpar(ftext1, ftext2)

read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_fpar(paragraph) %>% print()
```

The following is the output I received in the word document, not the properly formatted text from the example.  This is very very similar to what I was getting when using my own code.

Any idea how to make this look right? Thanks!

```
## rdocx document with 2 element(s)
## 
## * styles:
##                 Normal              heading 1              heading 2 
##            "paragraph"            "paragraph"            "paragraph" 
##              heading 3 Default Paragraph Font           Normal Table 
##            "paragraph"            "character"                "table" 
##                No List                 strong               centered 
##            "numbering"            "character"            "paragraph" 
##         table_template    Light List Accent 2            Titre 1 Car 
##                "table"                "table"            "character" 
##            Titre 2 Car            Titre 3 Car          Image Caption 
##            "character"            "character"            "paragraph" 
##          Table Caption     Table Professional                  toc 1 
##            "paragraph"                "table"            "paragraph" 
##                  toc 2           Balloon Text    Texte de bulles Car 
##            "paragraph"            "paragraph"            "character" 
##           reference_id          graphic title            table title 
##            "character"            "paragraph"            "paragraph" 
## 
## * Content at cursor location:
##   level num_id        text style_name content_type
## 1    NA     NA hello World         NA    paragraph
```